# Making proxies of all objects in a Linked collection in blender 2.8

Tags: linked-data, collections, proxies

So, I see that we now use collections to group multiple objects and then link the whole collection in another file. But when I go to the linked collection, I have to go and make a proxy of each object one by one. Is there a way to make proxies of all objects in a collection automatically, as manually seems to take forever if your collection is pretty big.

Comment: recommended tutorial from Dr. Sybren Stuvel [Asset Linking | Scripting for Artists 12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIg-KOeFxkg&list=PLa1F2ddGya_8acrgoQr1fTeIuQtkSd6BW&index=7)

Answer (score 0):

You can parent all of the objects in the collection to an empty (and include the parent in the collection). Then, in the other file, link the collection and make a proxy to the parent. This should allow you to move, rotate, scale the entire linked collection.